# MC-Cordova-Plugin with hybrid remote

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, hybrid-remote

We are trying to implement Marketing Cloud Mobile Push in our hybrid remote app. We have installed the MC-Cordova-Plugin. Included the generated js file into the remote visualforce page but calling the methods has no effect. Is it possible to have Mobile Push work with hybrid remote apps?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things I don't understand about your environment yet. I don't know what you're doing in the "remote visualforce page" nor do I know what platforms you are trying to support. I'm assuming you are downloading and installing the latest plugin from the public repo https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin. That being said your best bet is to understand what is going on in the "CLI Workflow" section of our docs.

This section assumes that you have an existing app set-up with notifications, provisioned and turned on with bundleid set, etc; Those steps are commented to help give a bit of an understanding as to why we are copying your original project files, backing them up and then replacing the auto-generated ones created with the Cordova prepare command later. It does sound like you're integrating into an existing app. I'm also assuming the generated JS file you are referring to is our "MCCordovaPlugin.js" file correct?

1. What platforms are you supporting?
2. Have you been able to execute any of the build commands like "cordova plugin add", "cordova prepare"?
3. What do you mean by your question... "Is it possible to have Mobile Push work with hybrid remote apps?" The Cordova repo is a hybrid platform and does support mobile push SDK. At least the features supported in the ReadMe.

If you are in need of more in-depth support or a walkthrough, if you could contact your SF support rep, we would be happy to get you where you need to be.

Comment: The remote visualforce page is an empty page exposed through community from which we are trying to use the methods provided by the plugin. Ex: setContactKey so it registers with mobile push. We have downloaded the latest MC-Cordova plugin and added to our project following the CLI workflow already. Notifications are currently working when pushed from salesforce using the default plugin but the goal here is to push from Mobile push. We are looking to support iOS and Android but we are testing in iOS now.

Comment: We will try to contact SF support rep now, are you part of Mobile Push support? do you need us to refer your name or dept? Thanks.

Comment: Yes... that would be great. I'm part of the Marketing Cloud SDK team. Would be glad to help.